# Accessible HTML: Do I need to use aria-pressed AND aria-expanded on these buttons?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a list of buttons with state names that show/hide lists of cities in each of those states.

https://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/category_stihl

Click the orange "Find a Store" button in the "Only Sold in Stores" banner to show the UI in action.

[image: Find your nearest Stihl store UI Component]

I'm wondering if I need to use `aria-pressed` when I'm using `aria-expanded`. Wouldn't `aria-expanded` effectively set the button as pressed/toggled/active/in-use? Can I get rid of `aria-pressed`?

State buttons:

```
<ul id="state-list">
  <li role="button" aria-pressed="true" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Minnesota">Minnesota</li>
  <li role="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="NorthDakota">North Dakota</li>
  <li role="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</li>
  <li role="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Texas">Texas</li>
  <li role="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</li>
</ul>
```

City lists:

```
<ul aria-labelledby="Minnesota" class="cities Minnesota" style="display: block;">
  <li>City Name</li>
  <li>City Name</li>
  <li>City Name</li>
</ul>
<ul aria-labelledby="NorthDakota" class="cities NorthDakota" style="display: none;">
  <li>City Name</li>
  <li>City Name</li>
  <li>City Name</li>
</ul>
<ul aria-labelledby="Oklahoma" class="cities Oklahoma" style="display: none;">
  <li>City Name</li>
  <li>City Name</li>
  <li>City Name</li>
</ul>
etc...
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern is not an accordion. You are separating the headers from the panels. This pattern is [tabs](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel), where tabs are separated from tabpanels.

To first answer your question, ARIA mentions neither for tabs, nor for accordions `aria-pressed`. So the answer would be NO, you don't need that.

---

Based on your code there also seems to be some misunderstandings of what the used attributes do.

- `aria-labelledby` should include the ID of another element, not a string (that would be `aria-label`
- You don't need to use a `aria-label` at all if the text is already in accessible HTML. It's just cloaking your HTML
- ARIA attributes will not fix your keyboard navigation

A basic principle of ARIA is that you should avoid it and prefer semantic HTML instead. [No ARIA is better than Bad ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#no_aria_better_bad_aria)

Instead of giving an `<li>` a duplicate (or triple) role, you should add a `<button>`. This will make sure your button is accessible to the most wide audience, including **keyboard** users.

[ARIA mentions a lot about tabpanel](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel), including required keyboard navigation patterns.

Here would be your HTML code reworked, but remember that you'll need **JavaScript** to take care of the active tab that has `aria-selected="true"` and to establish a [roving tab index](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#kbd_roving_tabindex).

```
<p id="tabtitle">Northern Tool + Equipment sells Stihl products in the following locations:</p>

<ul id="state-list" role="tablist" aria-labelledby="tabtitle">
  <li><button aria-selected="true" role="tab" aria-controls="minnesota-tab" id="minnesota">Minnesota</button></li>
  <li><button role="tab" aria-controls="north-dakota-tab" id="north-dakota" tabindex="-1">North Dakota</button></li>
  …
</ul>

<ul 
  tabindex="0"
  role="tabpanel"
  id="minnesota-tab"
  aria-labelledby="minnesota"
  class="cities Minnesota"
  >
  <li>City Name</li>
  <li>City Name</li>
  <li>City Name</li>
</ul>
<ul
  tabindex="0"
  role="tabpanel"
  id="north-dakota-tab"
  aria-labelledby="north-dakota"
  class="cities North Dakota"
  hidden
  >
  <li>City Name</li>
  <li>City Name</li>
  <li>City Name</li>
</ul>
…
```

Comment: The [hidden attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) is HTML 5.1, and browsers apply per default a `display: none`.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to mention that there is no such thing as "aria-role". It is just "role". Example: role="tablist", etc.